# Autofill range syntax and dynamic range selection

Tags: vba, excel

I need to have VBA put a specific formula in a range of cells, so as to create a matrix, this range needs to change size based on the number of data points. Here is a general outline of what I am looking to do.

```
Sub Input_Formulas()
'Dim Target_2 as String <= Name of sheet
'Dim Row_Limit1 as Long <= Number of Rows
'Dim Row_Limit2 as Long <= Number of Colums
'Dim Row_Count as Long <= Total number of rows aka. total number of data points

Range("C3").Select '<= This will stay the same in all sheets

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(R21C18:R71C18,RC2,R21C22:R71C22,R2C)" '<= The formula will stay the same but I need the range to move based on the total number of rows

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C3:G3"), Type:=xlFillDefault '<= The destination range needs to change based on Row_Limit2

Range("C3:G3").Select '<= Also needs to change based on Row_Limit2

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C3:G16"), Type:=xlFillDefault '<= Needs to change based on Row_Limit1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the last column in Row 3

`LstCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Find the last row in Column B

`LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

Set the range from C3 to Last Row & Last Column

`Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(LstRw, LstCol))`

Put the formula in that range

`Rng = "=COUNTIFS($R$21:$R$71,$B3,$V$21:$V$71,C$2)"`

### Full code

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim LstCol As Long
    Dim LstRw As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim S As String

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With sh
        LstCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(LstRw, LstCol))

        Rng = "=COUNTIFS($R$21:$R$71,$B3,$V$21:$V$71,C$2)"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like this will put the formula in the correct places. The next step I would see would be getting the range within the CountIfs to move based on how much data there is in the various columns. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your formula only uses column R & V